# Pandas resample and add size as a column

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

Given a dataframe:

```
Index       A  B
2016-01-01  5  10
2016-01-01  1  2
2016-01-02  1  1
```

Is it possible to resample the DataFrame using sum and add a column to the end of the DataFrame which includes the count of observations in the bins such that the result is:

```
Index      A  B  Count
2016-01-01 6  12 2
2016-01-02 1  1  1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) or [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.resample('D').agg({'A':'sum', 'B':['sum', 'size']})
print (df1)
             B        A
           sum size sum
Index                  
2016-01-01  12    2   6
2016-01-02   1    1   1

df2 = df.groupby(level=0).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':['sum', 'size']})
print (df2)
             B        A
           sum size sum
Index                  
2016-01-01  12    2   6
2016-01-02   1    1   1
```

If need remove `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df1 = df.resample('D').agg({'A':'sum', 'B':['sum', 'size']})
df1.columns = ['B','Count','A'] 
df1 = df1[['A','B','Count']]
print (df1)
            A   B  Count
Index                   
2016-01-01  6  12      2
2016-01-02  1   1      1

df2 = df.groupby(level=0).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':['sum', 'size']})
df2.columns = ['B','Count','A'] 
df2 = df2[['A','B','Count']]
print (df2)
            A   B  Count
Index                   
2016-01-01  6  12      2
2016-01-02  1   1      1
```

Comment: That is what I was trying to do. I didn't know you could feed a list into the agg() dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can also seed your data with an extra `count` column like so:

```
frame['count'] = 1  # A column of ones we can count
frame.resample(...).agg({
    'count': np.sum,
    'A': np.mean,
    ...
})
```

Or if you want to say, do a mean on all columns but the `count` column:

```
frame['count'] = 1
frame.resample(...).agg({
    # Default aggregation
    **{key: np.mean for key in frame.keys()},
    # Override `count`
    'count': np.sum,
    # other columns you want to override
})
```